# Python: Recursion problems

Tags: python, recursion, sudoku

I am trying to make a sudoku solver that solves boards very quickly.  At the moment my solver works on easy boards but never terminates on harder boards.  I believe it has something to do with my recursion because easy boards do not require recursion and hard boards do.  Any help is appreciated.

```
import sys

def rowno(i):
    return i // 9

def colno(i):
    return i % 9

def boxno(i):
    return (i // 9 // 3 )*3 + (i // 3) % 3

def isNeighbor(i, j):
    if rowno(i) == rowno(j) or colno(i) == colno(j) or boxno(i) == boxno(j):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def getFileName():
    if sys.platform == "win32":
            filename = input("Filename? ")
    else:
            filename = sys.argv[-1]
    return filename


solutionlist = []

class Board(object):
    def __init__(self, puzzle):
        self.puzzle = puzzle
        self.board = [Cell(int(value), idx) for idx, value in     enumerate(puzzle)]
        self.change = False

    def printAll(self):
        print [cell.candidates for cell in self.board] 
        #return str(" ")

    def update(self):
        self.change = False
        l = [cell for cell in self.board if len(cell.candidates) == 1]
        for i in l:
            for j in xrange(81):
                if isNeighbor(i.dex, j) and i.dex != j:
                    old = self.board[j].candidates
                    self.board[j].delCandidate(i.value)
                    if len(old) != len(self.board[j].candidates):
                        self.change = True

    def toString(self):
        str1 = ''.join(str(e.value) for e in self.board)
        return str1


    def solved(self):
        for cell in self.board:
            if len(cell.candidates) != 1:
                return False
        return True

    def solve(self):
        self.change = True
        while self.change == True:
            self.update()
        if self.solved():
            solutionlist.append(self.board)
            return
        l = [cell for cell in self.board if len(cell.candidates) > 1]
        for i in l:
            for j in i.candidates:
                newBoard = Board(self.toString())
                curLen = 12
                curCell = -1
                for u in l:
                    if len(u.candidates)<curLen:
                        curLen=len(u.candidates)
                        curCell = u.dex
                for c in newBoard.board[curCell].candidates:
                    newBoard.board[curCell].candidates = [int(c)]
                    newBoard.board[curCell].value = int(c)
                    newBoard.solve()
        return



    def __repr__(self):
        l = [cell.value for cell in self.board] 
        return str(l)


class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, value, dex):
        self.value = value
        self.dex = dex
        if value == 0:
            self.candidates = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        else:
            self.candidates = [int(value)]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def delCandidate(self, value):
        # deletes value from candidate list
        #return self.candidate.remove(value);
        self.candidates = [x for x in self.candidates if x != value]
        if len(self.candidates) == 1:
            self.value = self.candidates[0]
easy =     "700583006006001405052006083300200958500078060648010300060802500003150072215600030"
twosol = "000805200800000401705040009000100702040000000006430000030900000010006080000000000"
hard = "040090008000000070060000120030020000005839060080600700050170600000043000003000200"

#easy solution: 794583216836721495152496783371264958529378164648915327967832541483159672215647839

b = Board(hard)
print b

b.solve()
print "end of the line"
for i in solutionlist:
    print [cell.value for cell in i]
    print "\n"
```

Comment: good luck ... i hate sudoku so much

Comment: So what is your exact question? Or are you just showing off?

Comment: @Lawrence the question is in regards to me being unable to find the issue.  Really just asking for any errors to be pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major issue is the line `for i in l:` in the `solve` method.  Since you're recursing, you only need to fill in one cell - the recursion will take care of the rest.  So instead of `for i in l:`, just recurse on the one cell that is the best candidate (curCell):

```
    l = [cell for cell in self.board if len(cell.candidates) > 1]
    if len(l) > 0:
        newBoard = Board(self.toString())
        curLen = 12
        curCell = -1
        for u in l:
            if len(u.candidates)<curLen:
                curLen=len(u.candidates)
                curCell = u.dex
        for c in newBoard.board[curCell].candidates:
            newBoard.board[curCell].candidates = [int(c)]
            newBoard.board[curCell].value = int(c)
            newBoard.solve()
```

Comment: To which `for i in l:` are you referring to? It appears multiple times in the code

Comment: Are you suggesting something like `if len(l) == 0:
            print self
            return
        for j in l[0].candidates:`

Comment: I meant the one in solve().  Now that I'm looking at your code more closely, I think it was even less necessary than I thought - you're already trying to pick the best candidate with `for u in l`, so what's the point of the two outer loops?  I've updated my answer with suggested code.

Comment: Good call with the outer loops, they definitely are not both needed. After implementing your code the program still does not terminate, but I believe you are pointing me in a good direction

Comment: It seems that the while statement before the recursion incorrectly replaces the value of cells that have not been solved for with a 1